# Creating copy constructor for class with a pointer member on the heap

Tags: c++, xerces-c

**Short version:**  Can I safely create a copy constructor for a class that has member pointer variables, one of which is on the heap, that are of type `xercesc::XercesDOMParser*` and `xercesc::DOMDocument*`?  If so, how?

**Long version:**

I wrote a class to wrap a Xercesc document object.  It has two member variables that are pointers to a `XercesDOMParser` and a `DOMDocument`.  Here is the part of the class declaration that shows those two members:

```
class XMLigator {
private:
    xercesc::XercesDOMParser* _pParser;
    xercesc::DOMDocument* _pDocument;
    etc...
```

The pointers `_pParser` and `_pDocument` are initialized in the constructor.  Here is an abbreviated version of the constructor with the relevant code.  Notice that `_pParser` is created with the `new` operator and is on the heap:

```
XMLigator::XMLigator(string strFile) : _strFile(strFile), _pDocument(NULL) {
    xercesc::XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize();
    _pParser = new xercesc::XercesDOMParser();  
    _pParser->parse(_strFile.c_str());
    _pDocument = _pParser->getDocument();
}
```

The destructor deletes the member variable `_pParser`:

```
XMLigator::~XMLigator(void) {
    if (m_pParser) {
        delete _pParser;
    }
}
```

Until now I have prohibited the copy constructor and assignment operator by marking them private and not defining them.

Now I would like to, if possible, create a copy constructor for this class so I can make it a return type for a function, in this fashion:

```
XMLigator getOne() {
    XMLigator xml("/some/file.xml");
    return xml;
}
```

The first problem I see is my the destructor does a `delete _pParser;`.  So I think that's a problem.  I am pretty sure I have to remove the `delete` from the destructor.  But then I have a memory leak.

I really have no idea how to approach this.  Maybe it's not possible.  Does anyone have an approach that I can use for this?

Comment: Is the downvoter trying to tell me that my question is poorly asked or that I shouldn't try to make a copy constructor for this class?  Or something else?

Comment: (I am not the downvoter.) Does `XercesDOMParser` have a (public) copy ctor? And are you sure you want `getOne()` to return an object, and not a pointer?

Comment: Since your class owns a resource (memory) you probably do need a _copy constructor_ and _copy assignment operator_. See: [What is The Rule of Three?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: @Beta, I'll answer the second question first.  I am not married to the idea of returning an object rather than pointer or reference.  I was just thinking it would be nice if I returned an object (with an approrpriate copy constructor) that would do it's own cleanup when it goes out of scope in the caller (like occurs with `std::string` or `std::vector`).  If I return a pointer I believe the caller might need to do cleanup explicitly with a `delete` or some form of `release()` method of my own creation.  For the first question I have to do some research...

Comment: You don't have to do much research, just try it.